# cake 2.1 data validation not working

Tags: cakephp-2.1, validation

I tried every method, but it cake php data validation does not working.would you tell me what is the wrong part?
I add all types of validations but still the form saves without validation data!

My model:

```
class contacts extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'contact';
    public $useTable='contacts';    
    public $validate=array(
        'name' => array(
            'requierd'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('Not empty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
        )
    );

}
```

My controller

```
class ContactsController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers=array('Html','Form');
    public $components=array('session','Email');

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
             $this->Contact->create();
            if($this->Contact->save($this->request->data))
            {

                $this->Session->setFlash('Thank you we will contact you soon');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to send your message.');
            }

        }

    }
}
```

My view:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Contact');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('subject');
echo $this->Form->input('message',array('rows' => '3'));
//echo $this->Form->checkbox('Send me a coppy');
echo $this->Form->end('Send');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
public $validate=array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'A username is required'
    )
);
```

as seen in the [docs example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3anotEmpty). Don't know why you added an extra array.

You can add `required` and `allowEmpty` indexes just to be strict-er

```
public $validate=array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'A username is required',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. the reason that they were not working was because the model name!!